# AngularJS for each select distinct

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Say I have an object like this

```
$scope.products = {
 blueDuck: {type:'duck', price: 5},
 redDuck: {type:'duck', price: 8},
 greenWolverine: {type:'wolverine', price:15}
}
```

I want to loop over the elements by type:

```
angular.forEach($scope.products, function(key, value) {
   console.log(value.type);
});
```

That would output:

```
duck
duck
wolverine
```

When I want to get a variable that's like:

```
duck
wolverine
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 var items = []; //The temporary array to keep the values
 angular.forEach($scope.products, function(key,value) {
     if(items.indexOf(value) === -1) { //Check if the values is not already in the temp array
         items.push(key); //Push it to array
     }
 });
console.log(items); //Show the content of the array
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. Added it.

Answer (score 0):

you can store the variables coming from the loop inside an `array`, and check if the array contains your data from the `loop`. this is something i came up with

```
 var items = [];
 angular.forEach($scope.products, function(key,value) {
          if(items.indexOf(value) === -1) {
              items.push(key);
              console.log(value.type);
          }
      });
```

Comment: This will only print the values if they are repeated. console.log should be outside the loop in that case. See my answer

Comment: seriously you had to copy paste my code as an answer.you should have suggested an edit.